# Translate (transform) header in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a `table` and I want to move the `header` using `translate` in css. I can do this in Chrome but not in IE 11.

I tried the following and it moves in IE 11 but the problem is that it doesn't take the whole available width: https://jsfiddle.net/2mmm18ce/

I cannot use any 3rd party library (such as jQuery).

Any pure css solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to play a little with the properties of the header

Add display and position as follows

```css
table{
}
thead{
  display: table-caption;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(0px, 30px);
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      h1
    </th>
    <th>
      h2
    </th>
    <th>
      h3
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
  <td>
    v1
  </td>
  <td>
    v2
  </td>
  <td>
    v3
  </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why the header is not aligned with the body any more ? The column are not aligned.

Comment: doesn't help as alligment is destroyed, also the transition while smooth in chrome is jumping in ie

Answer (score 0):

Translating `thead` doesn't work in IE or Edge. Translate `th` instead.